# operator overloading (+), (++), ([]), (=) and (*)

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

I am trying to overload some operators in a class.

Operators to load: (+), (=), (++), (*) and ([])

So basically I have a class A and an array, I want to use operator [] to return v[index]

I want to use operator + to add the corresponding array elements

I tried to do it but it seems like I am missing something.

I have a test case in the main routine, and whenever I run my code, I get the following errors:

```
(78): error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'int' (or there is no acceptable conversion)


(67): could be 'A &A::operator =(const A &)'


(82): error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand (67): could be 'A &A::operator =(const A &)'


(87): warning C4620: no postfix form of 'operator ++' found for type 'A', using prefix form


(6) : see declaration of 'A'
```

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#define NUM  10

class A
{

    int v[NUM];

public:
    A() { }
    A(int x[]) {
        for (int i = 0; i<NUM; i++)
            v[i] = x[i];
    }

    // (1) operator: [ index ], which returns v[index]

    int &operator [](int i)
    {
        return v[i];
    }


    // (2) operator:  +,  which adds the corresponding array elements

    int operator+(const A& b)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM; i++)
        {
            return v[i] = v[i] + v[i + 1];
        }
    }

    // (3) operator:  *,  which multiplies the corresponding array Elements

    int operator*(const A& b)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM; i++)
        {
            return v[i] = v[i] * v[i + 1];
        }
    }

    // (4) operator:  ++, which adds each array element by 1

    int operator++()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM; i++)
        {
            return v[i++];
        }
    }

    // (5) operator:  =, which assigns all the array elements from one object to another

/*  void operator=(const A& b)
    {
    } */


        // a print function to print out all the array elements

        void print();


};

int main()
{

    int x[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    A b1(x), b2, b3, b4, b5;
    cout << "b1[5]: " << b1[5] << endl;
    b2 = b1;
    cout << "b2:  ";
    b2.print();
    b3 = b1 + b2;
    cout << "b3:  ";
    b3.print();

    b4 = b1*b2;
    cout << "b4:  ";
    b4.print();

    b5 = b4;
    b5++;
    cout << "b5:  ";
    b5.print();

}
```

I updated my code, now I have one error only (better than before):

the error is in line 76: 'A::A(const A &)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'int [10]' to 'const A &'

I see that it cannot convert x[0] from int to const A & which makes sense.  Should I change the operator[] to an int then?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#define NUM  10

class A
{

    int v[NUM];

public:
    A() {
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM; i++)
            v[i] = 0;
    }

    /* operator ([]) */

    int &operator[](int i)
    {
        return v[i];
    }

    /* operator (+) */

    A operator+(const A& b)
    {
        A result;
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM; i++)
        {
            result.v[i] = v[i] + b.v[i];
        }
    }

    /* operator (*) */

    A operator*(const A& b)
    {
        A result;
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM; i++)
        {
            result.v[i] = v[i] * b.v[i];
        }
    }

    /* operator (=) */

    A operator=(const A& b)
    {
        A result;
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM; i++)
        {
            result.v[i] = b.v[i];
        }
    }

    /* operator (++) */

    A operator++(int)
    {
        A result;
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM; i++)
        {
            result.v[i]++;
        }
    }

        void print();


};

int main()
{

    int x[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    A b1(x), b2, b3, b4, b5;
    cout << "b1[5]: " << b1[5] << endl;
    b2 = b1;
    cout << "b2:  ";
    b2.print();
    b3 = b1 + b2;
    cout << "b3:  ";
    b3.print();

    b4 = b1*b2;
    cout << "b4:  ";
    b4.print();

    b5 = b4;
    b5++;
    cout << "b5:  ";
    b5.print();

}
```

Comment: What would those errors be?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Element-wise operations in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20457452/element-wise-operations-in-c)

Comment: Why don't you even use `b` in all those operators? Please turn on compiler warnings (and look at them, and understand them, and respect them).

Comment: I guess that's why I posted here? @leemes

Comment: There's so much wrong about your code. I don't even know where to start. Maybe try to understand what `return` does and why it doesn't make sense to put it in your loop. Also try to understand why it doesn't make sense to have a parameter which you don't use. I don't mean to be rude or something; I simply recommend taking **small steps**. You seem to be at the very beginning of learning C++.

Comment: Not related but your operators are returning from inside the loop so only the first item in the loop will be dealt with.

Comment: @user3263914 Please see the help center post about what counts as a ["Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). There are nuances to the various operator overloadings, and you will need to be able to *"walk before you can run"*...so if you are having trouble getting any part of your program working just talk about that. It's enough to mention addition without multiplication, for instance. Keep it short and "think out loud" a bit about what evidence you have for *expecting* the code to behave a certain way, and why you don't feel you're just making things up!

Comment: Well you commented out the `operator+` function so, yeah, no real surprise that the compiler can't find it...

Comment: Your constructor doesn't modify the array so should take as `const int x[]`

Comment: @user3263914 Can't tell if that's sarcasm or not, but...you're non-sarcastically welcome in either case.  I think it's good advice to effectively use the resource of StackOverflow, which can seem very randomly harsh if one doesn't "know the rules" that are more invisible than they should be.  I like to try and offer practical advice vs a downvote (which does not communicate much IMO).

Comment: @HostileFork It is very harsh.  In my first post, I got -6 votes and I swear I did all I could to explain my question and what I want my algorithm to do.

Comment: @user3263914 Don't sweat the downvotes, it's just triage.  You'll be fine.  I didn't downvote you and I almost never downvote people, especially new users.  I helped to explain why, to help you in the future, because there really are better ways to frame up questions--just as there are better ways to code.  In ways, I think learning how to ask and frame questions could be just as beneficial as the code learning that goes on here.  If only people [were a bit nicer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9953/) about teaching that part (that tech heads care a bit less about, usually).

Comment: @user3263914 `cannot convert argument 1 from 'int [10]' to 'const A &'` comes from not having a constructor that understands `A b1(x)`, where `int x[] = { 1, 2 ...`. I know it's not be the answer you want to hear, but there are "too many questions in this question". It's a bit of the deep end of the pool to be jumping in and expecting a quick solution. If you sought to write a trivial-but-correct implementation of `std::vector` you'd see there are many i's to dot and t's to cross. I'll upvote you as goodwill but vote to close this question; try picking ONE aspect to ask about.

Answer (score 1):

The return type of `operator+` (and also some other operators) and the early `return' calls are wrong. Here is how to fix it.

```
A() {
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM; i++) {
        v[i] = 0;
    }
}

A operator+(const A& b) {
    A result;  // result is initialized with 0s.
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM; i++) {
        result.v[i] = v[i] + b.v[i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

An alternative, without changing the constructor:

```
A operator+(const A& b) {
    A result = *this;
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM; i++) {
        result.v[i] += b.v[i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Should I do the same thing for the other operators? I mean this part: "A operator+(const A& b)" should it always be the same or it depends on the operator?

Comment: @user3263914 C++ has fairly flexible semantics with the overloading.  There's nothing saying that you can't write it so that `a + b` of two vector-like things returns the sum of all the elements of both vectors as a single value vs. another vector-like thing.  `+` might not have anything to do with addition whatsoever...you can `+` a FOO to a BAR and get a BAZ for any FOO, BAR, BAZ *(well, non-"POD" input types)*.  You can read the section in the [C++ "FQA"](http://yosefk.com/c++fqa/operator.html#fqa-13.1) and in general, a good resource for putting C++ complexity in perspective.